# data-ajax-update and data-ajax-mode="replace" not working in dotnet core jquery unobtrusive ajax

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, unobtrusive-ajax

I have an anchor which should replace a grid with a partial view .

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" 
                        data-ajax="true" 
                        data-ajax-method="GET"
                        data-ajax-mode="replace"
                        data-ajax-update="content"
                        data-ajax-url="@Url.Action("add","user")"> Create User </a>
 <div class="row table-area">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="content">
        @Html.AjaxGrid(Url.Action("results", "user"))
    </div>
</div>
```

I see it calls the user action with partial view but it never updates the section with `id="content"`.

Here is my controller method -

```
    [Route("add")]
    public IActionResult AddUser()
    {
        return PartialView("Partials/AddUser",new RegisterViewModel());
    }
```

Ideally it should replace the grid content with the partial view altogether but it is not replacing . The response status is 200 and I can see that the contents are being returned in response . Anybody has any idea what is the issue here ?

Comment: Have you tried changing`data-ajax-update="content"` to include in the id of the div like `data-ajax-update="#content"`

Comment: No I haven't tried that have to check that . But honestly I felt only giving `content ` should work

Comment: Did this resolve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change `data-ajax-update="content"` to `data-ajax-update="#content"`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using data-ajax-url, use the asp-controller and asp-action and the #content should work.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="user" asp-action="add" 
                        data-ajax="true" 
                        data-ajax-method="GET"
                        data-ajax-mode="replace"
                        data-ajax-update="#content">Create User</a>
```

Comment: That defeats the purpose of the ajax tag helper